# Classnames clashing in safari

Tags: safari, material-ui, next.js, jss

I got a very strange issue in safari. I am working on a project using nextjs, material-ui, jss.
My css works fine in safari when i run local server using `npm run dev` . but after going to production or when i create production build on my machine by running `yarn build`, my css gets totally messed up. when i inspected in dev tools i found that after building, different classnames are resolving to same classenames for example :-

[image]

refer the image above, we have 2 classnames i.e `.jss36` while in my code these 2 are different classnames

[image]

the same issue is throughout all the page and css is completely messed up. i have no idea why this is happening

It works fine in chrome

[image]

Comment: are these two css in the same file or different? Can you show directory structure that contains the css files and component files for it?

Comment: these are in the same file and are for same component. and this css code is not in .css file. i am using jss(Mui's makeStyles-createStyles) and it's written in the same file

Comment: Also, show how classes are being used. I have a project, and it is working fine for me. So maybe the problem is with the usage. Show how the stylings are written in the makeStylne, and how it is used in the component.

Comment: ok @SirajAlam i am editing the question and adding screenshots there